# Should I postpone my MEXT scholarship application process until 2021 due coronavirus outbreak?

Tags: funding, japan

The next month I plan to apply for MEXT scholarship for a PhD study. My study proposal is almost ready and I have my thesis already written in English. But due coronavirus outbreak I was thinking to do anything I can to be prepared and on the next year actually apply for.

The main reason is because I plan to wait for a vaccine first for coronavirus, because my N5 level of Japanese may not be enough to communicate with a doctor in order to receive a vaccine. Though I was successfully examined and received a JPLT N5 Certification.

Do you think that is a good plan?

Comment: No. Continue. Japan is very safe country

Comment: What would you gain by waiting? If you get it, and can't start anyway, would that be worse than not applying and not starting anyway?

Comment: Yes because if I get accepted on scholarship and get accepted but I cannot travel then I may cannot reapply !! But if I apply once the coronavirus things get settle down then I would be more prepared (I would know more japaneese) and my paperwork sorted out better.

Comment: What makes you believe this crisis will be over in 2021?

Comment: I assume in 2021 will be over because the whole medical scientific community currently works both on treatment and on vaccine. Also in SARS and in H1N1 age the vaccine has been developed in months. Hence I think if I give some time the outbreak will calm down. Also by applying in 2021 instead now I will start my PhD in 2022.

Comment: The information I have seen suggests that it will take more than a year to get a vaccine. Then it needs to be produced an distributed. So make that a minimum of two years. This is in line with the predictions from the relevant authorities in my country. This is much more serious than SARS or h1n1. The best thing you can do is treat this as a marathon rather than a sprint.

Comment: You mean to prepare my paperwork for any open opportunity for applying the MEXT ASAP right? What kind it the marathon in my case?

Comment: With marathon I meant that you need to consider what you are going to do when the crisis lasts years. Silutions like waiting are probably not going to work on such a scenario.

Answer (score 2):

At this point there are no guarantees. Things could be fine in a year or not. There could be a vaccine or not. Japan could be doing well or not. The pool of applicants could be stronger then or not. Travel may be easier or not. There are just too many variables.

Under the circumstances you are probably best advised to continue on with an application until you reach a firm decision point (acceptance, say). Perhaps more will be known then. But expect chaos in the near term. Too many governments are behaving incompetently and making bad decisions. That could change or not.

Comment: On the other hand I could wait to settle the chaos and then be prepared well to apply. For example if there's a travel ban and keeps on my country but I get accepted then What? 

I cannot travel! !!.

Comment: On the other-other-hand there is no telling when the chaos will subside. At some level of chaos political conflict comes into play - and worse. If you get accepted and can't travel, I would guess people would try to let you delay. Just keep them informed.